# matlab error particleswarm Objective function must return scalar values

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem using PARTICLESWARM function in MATLAB2014b. with aid of Open Source ECG Toolbox, version 1.0, November 2006 Released under the GNU General Public License.

The main objective of the code is to find the optimal parameters of the ECG model to achieve the minimum model error.

I have used PSO as optimizer to find these optimal parameters. Itends up with error:

```
Error using particleswarm>makeState (line 683)
Objective function must return scalar values.
Error in particleswarm>pswcore (line 164)
state = makeState(nvars,lbMatrix,ubMatrix,objFcn,options);
Error in particleswarm (line 146)
[x,fval,exitFlag,output] = pswcore(objFcn,nvars,lbRow,ubRow,output,options);
Error in ECGOptimizeModel (line 16)
param = particleswarm(@(InitParams) ECGModelError(InitParams,x,meanphase,0),length(InitParams),InitParams-2,InitParams+2,options)
Error in MY_ECGBeatFitterAuto (line 139)
[params model er] = ECGOptimizeModel(y, indx, meanphase);cannot continue
```

My functions is here:

```
function b = BaseLine1(x,L,approach)
%
% b = BaseLine1(x,L,approach),
% Baseline wander extraction from biomedical recordings, using a single 
% stage of median or moving average filtering.
%
% inputs:
% x: vector or matrix of noisy data (channels x samples)
% L: averaging window length (in samples)
% approach:
%   'md': median filtering
%   'mn': moving average
%
% output:
% b: vector or matrix of baseline wanders (channels x samples)
%
%
% Open Source ECG Toolbox, version 1.0, November 2006
% Released under the GNU General Public License
% Copyright (C) 2006  Reza Sameni
% Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran -- GIPSA-Lab, INPG, Grenoble, France
% reza.sameni@gmail.com

% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
% under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
% Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
% option) any later version.
% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
% Public License for more details.

N = size(x,2);
b = zeros(size(x));
flen = floor(L/2);

if (strcmp(approach,'mn'))      % moving average filter
    for j = 1:N,
        index = max(j-flen,1):min(j+flen,N);
        b(:,j) = mean(x(:,index),2);
    end
elseif (strcmp(approach,'md'))  % median filter
    for j = 1:N,
        index = max(j-flen,1):min(j+flen,N);
        b(:,j) = median(x(:,index),2);
    end
end
```

---

```
function y = LPFilter(x,fc)
%
% y = LPFilter(x,fc),
% Second order zero-phase Lowpass filter
%
% inputs:
% x: vector or matrix of input data (channels x samples)
% fc: -3dB cut-off frequency normalized by the sampling frequency
%
% output:
% y: vector or matrix of filtered data (channels x samples)
%
%
% Open Source ECG Toolbox, version 1.0, November 2006
% Released under the GNU General Public License
% Copyright (C) 2006  Reza Sameni
% Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran -- GIPSA-Lab, INPG, Grenoble, France
% reza.sameni@gmail.com

% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
% under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
% Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
% option) any later version.
% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
% Public License for more details.


k = .7;     % cut-off value
alpha = (1-k*cos(2*pi*fc)-sqrt(2*k*(1-cos(2*pi*fc))-k^2*sin(2*pi*fc)^2))/(1-k);
y = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:size(x,1)
    y(i,:) = filtfilt(1-alpha,[1 -alpha],x(i,:));
end
```

---

```
function [ECGmean,ECGsd,meanPhase] = MeanECGExtraction(x,phase,bins,flag)
%
% [ECGmean,ECGsd,meanPhase] = MeanECGExtraction(x,phase,bins,flag)
% Calculation of the mean and SD of ECG waveforms in different beats
%
% inputs:
% x: input ECG signal
% phase: ECG phase
% bins: number of desired phase bins
% flag
%     1: aligns the baseline on zero, by using the mean of the first 10%
%     segment of the calculated mean ECG beat
%     0: no baseline alignment
%
% outputs:
% ECGmean: mean ECG beat
% ECGsd: standard deviation of ECG beats
% meanPhase: the corresponding phase for one ECG beat
%
%
% Open Source ECG Toolbox, version 2.0, March 2008
% Released under the GNU General Public License
% Copyright (C) 2008  Reza Sameni
% Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran -- LIS-INPG, Grenoble, France
% reza.sameni@gmail.com

% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
% under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
% Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
% option) any later version.
% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
% Public License for more details.

meanPhase = zeros(1,bins);
ECGmean = zeros(1,bins);
ECGsd = zeros(1,bins);

I = find( phase>=(pi-pi/bins)  | phase<(-pi+pi/bins) );
if(~isempty(I))
    meanPhase(1) = -pi;
    ECGmean(1) = mean(x(I));
    ECGsd(1) = std(x(I));
else
    meanPhase(1) = 0;
    ECGmean(1) =0;
    ECGsd(1) = -1;
end
for i = 1 : bins-1;
    I = find( phase >= 2*pi*(i-0.5)/bins-pi & phase < 2*pi*(i+0.5)/bins-pi );
    if(~isempty(I))
        meanPhase(i + 1) = mean(phase(I));
        ECGmean(i + 1) = mean(x(I));
        ECGsd(i + 1) = std(x(I));
    else
        meanPhase(i + 1) = 0;
        ECGmean(i + 1) = 0;
        ECGsd(i + 1) = -1;
    end
end
K = find(ECGsd==-1);
for i = 1:length(K),
    switch K(i)
        case 1
            meanPhase(K(i)) = -pi;
            ECGmean(K(i)) = ECGmean(K(i)+1);
            ECGsd(K(i)) = ECGsd(K(i)+1);
        case bins
            meanPhase(K(i)) = pi;
            ECGmean(K(i)) = ECGmean(K(i)-1);
            ECGsd(K(i)) = ECGsd(K(i)-1);
        otherwise
            meanPhase(K(i)) = mean([meanPhase(K(i)-1),meanPhase(K(i)+1)]);
            ECGmean(K(i)) = mean([ECGmean(K(i)-1),ECGmean(K(i)+1)]);
            ECGsd(K(i)) = mean([ECGsd(K(i)-1),ECGsd(K(i)+1)]);
    end
end

if(flag==1)
    ECGmean = ECGmean - mean(ECGmean(1:ceil(length(ECGmean)/10)));
end
```

---

```
function phase = PhaseShifting(phasein,teta)
%
% phase = PhaseShifting(phasein,teta),
% Phase shifter.
%
% inputs:
% phasein: calculated ECG phase
% teta: desired phase shift. teta>0 and teta<0 corresponds with phase leads
% and phase lags, respectively.
%
% output:
% phase: the shifted phase.

phase = phasein + teta;
phase = mod(phase + pi, 2*pi) - pi;
```

---

```
function [phase phasepos] = PhaseCalculation(peaks)

phasepos = zeros(1,length(peaks));

I = find(peaks);
for i = 1:length(I)-1;
    m = I(i+1) - I(i);
    phasepos(I(i)+1:I(i+1)) = 2*pi/m : 2*pi/m : 2*pi;
end
m = I(2) - I(1);
L = length(phasepos(1:I(1)));
phasepos(1:I(1)) = 2*pi-(L-1)*2*pi/m:2*pi/m:2*pi;

m = I(end) - I(end-1);
L = length(phasepos(I(end)+1:end));
phasepos(I(end)+1:end) = 2*pi/m:2*pi/m:L*2*pi/m;

phasepos = mod(phasepos,2*pi);

phase = phasepos; 
I = find(phasepos>pi);
phase(I) = phasepos(I) - 2*pi;
```

---

```
function E = ECGModelError(X,ECGmn,Phasemn,flag);
%
% Synthetic ECG model error
%
% Open Source ECG Toolbox, version 1.0, November 2006
% Released under the GNU General Public License
% Copyright (C) 2006  Reza Sameni
% Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran -- LIS-INPG, Grenoble, France
% reza.sameni@gmail.com

% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
% under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
% Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
% option) any later version.
% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
% Public License for more details. You should have received a copy of the
% GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the
% Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
% MA  02110-1301, USA.

L = (length(X)/3);

alphai = X(1:L);
bi = X(L+1:2*L);
tetai = X(2*L+1:3*L);

Z = zeros(size(ECGmn));
for j = 1:length(alphai),
    dtetai = rem(Phasemn - tetai(j) + pi,2*pi)-pi;
    Z = Z + alphai(j) .* exp(-dtetai .^2 ./ (2*bi(j) .^ 2));
end

if(flag==0)
    E = (Z-ECGmn);
elseif(flag==1)
    E = (Z);
end
```

---

```
function [params model er] = ECGOptimizeModel(x, indexes, meanphase)
tetai = meanphase(indexes);
alphai = 1*x(indexes); %1.2
bi = .01*ones(size(alphai));%0.04

% options = optimset('TolX',1e-4,'TolFun',1e-4,'MaxIter',100);
%%%options = optimset('TolX',1e-4,'TolFun',1e-4,'MaxIter',50,'Display','off');
InitParams = [alphai bi tetai];

 %params = nlinfit(meanphase,x,@ECGModel,InitParams,options);
%%%params = lsqnonlin(@(InitParams) ECGModelError(InitParams,x,meanphase,0),InitParams,InitParams-2,InitParams+2,options);

rng default
options = optimoptions('particleswarm','SwarmSize',50,'HybridFcn',@fminsearch);
%fun =@ECGModelError(InitParams,x,meanphase,0);
param = particleswarm(@(InitParams) ECGModelError(InitParams,x,meanphase,0),length(InitParams),InitParams-2,InitParams+2,options)

% Model0 = ECGModelError(InitParams,x,meanphase,1);
model = ECGModelError(params,x,meanphase,1);
er = 100*mean((x-model).^2)/mean(x.^2);
```

---

```
clc
clear all
close all;
**%  THE MAIN CODE**
load('SampleECG2.mat'); data = data(1:15000,3)';

fs = 1000;
t = [0:length(data)-1]/fs;

f = 1;                                          % approximate R-peak frequency

bsline = LPFilter(data,.7/fs);                  % baseline wander removal (may be replaced by other approaches)
x = data - bsline +.5*randn(size(data));
peaks = PeakDetection(x,f/fs);                  % peak detection
%peaks = PeakDetection2(x,fs); 
[phase phasepos] = PhaseCalculation(peaks);     % phase calculation

%% peak detection (Pan-Tompkins)
%peaks2 = PeakDetection2(x,fs);      % peak detection (Pan-Tompkins)
%figure;
%plot(t,x,'b');
%hold on
%plot(t,peaks2.*x,'go');
%xlabel('time (sec.)');
%ylabel('ECG Peaks(Pan-Tompkins)')
%%
teta = 0;                                       % desired phase shift
pphase = PhaseShifting(phase,teta);             % phase shifting

bins = fs/2;                                     % number of phase bins
[ECGmean,ECGsd,meanphase] = MeanECGExtraction(x,pphase,bins,1);


%% ECGBeatFitterAuto(ECGmean,meanphase)
% inputs:
% ECGmean:      the input ECG beat
% meanphase:    the phase signal of the ECG beat
% approach:     'fixed number' or 'min error'
% stopth:       stopping threshold error percentage
% divisions:    number of divisions for random point approach
% maxit:        maximum number of iterations for randomized methods
% energyth:     the energy threshold used for detecting peaks (default: 0.001)
% wlen:         peak search window length (default: 0.01*SignalLength)

% beat length
N = length(ECGmean);

% idle segment at the beginning of the beat
L0 = ceil(N/10);

stopth = .001; % percentage of error
num = 10;
maxitr = 10;
approach = 'min error'; % fixed number/min error
energyth = 0.0001;
th=energyth;
wlen = 3;

%% preprocessing
base = median(ECGmean(1:L0));
x = ECGmean - base;
y = BaseLine1(x,5,'md');%LPFilter(d,25/N);
% y = wden(x,'rigrsure','s','mln',6,'coif5');
y = LPFilter(y,45/N);

% % % figure;
% % % hold on;
% % % plot(x);
% % % plot(y,'r');
% % % grid

%% approach,'min error'
if(strcmp(approach,'min error'))

 % zero crossing detection
    zc = [0 y(1:end-1).*y(2:end)];
    I = find(zc<=0);
    E = sum(x.^2);
    II = [];
    m0 = find(I>L0,1);
    m = m0;
    for i = m0:length(I),
        ind = I(m):I(i);
        if(sum(x(ind).^2)>th*E)
            if(isempty(II))
                II = [I(m) I(i)];
            else
                II = [II I(i)];
            end
            m = m + 1;
        end
    end

    %//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    % local peak detection

    pk = zeros(1,N);
    for i = L0:N-L0,
        ind = max(i-wlen,1):min(i+wlen,N);
        if(y(i)==max(y(ind)) && y(i)>0 && std(y(ind))~=0) % local max with positive amplitudes
            pk(i) = 1;
        elseif(y(i)==min(y(ind)) && y(i)<0 && std(y(ind))~=0) % local min with negative amplitudes
            pk(i) = 1;
        end
    end
    J = find(pk);

    E = sum(y.^2);
    JJ = [];
    m0 = find(J>L0,1);
    m = m0;
    for i = m0:length(J),
        ind = J(m):J(i);
        if(sum(y(ind).^2)>th*E)
            if(isempty(JJ))
                JJ = [J(m) J(i)];
            else
                JJ = [JJ J(i)];
            end
            m = m + 1;
        end
    end

    %//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    % merge the results
    K = sort([I J]);
    KK = sort([II JJ]);

    % uniform points
    UU = L0:round(N/num):N-L0;

    %plot(zc),hold on,plot(JJ,zc(JJ),'m*')

    %% start optimizing
    done = logical(0);
    % peaks alone
    if(~done)
        indx = JJ;
        [params model er] = ECGOptimizeModel(y, indx, meanphase);
        indexes = indx;
        if(er<stopth)
            method = 0;
            done = 1;
        end
    end

if(~done)
        disp('Info: The specified requirements have not been met with fixed error model; continuing with random point approach.');
        approach = 'fixed number';
    end
elseif(strcmp(approach,'fixed number'))

%% uniform points
    UU = L0:round((N-2*L0)/num):N-L0;
    er = 100;
    for i = 1:maxitr,
        indx = UU + round((rand(size(UU))-.5)*N/10);
        indx = sort(indx);
        indx = indx(indx>=1);
        indx = indx(indx<=N);
        [params_ model_ er_] = ECGOptimizeModel(y, indx, meanphase);
        if(er_<er)
            indexes = indx;
            params = params_;
            model = model_;
            er = er_;
            if(er<stopth)
                method = 13;
                done = 1;
                break;
            end
        end
    end
end

disp(['Final model fitting error percentage: ',num2str(er)]);

% plot the results
n = 1:length(x);
figure;
plot(n,x);
hold on;
plot(n,y,'r');
plot(n,model,'k','LineWidth',2);
plot(n(indexes),x(indexes),'ro','linewidth',2);
grid

% % % grid
 disp(['Error = ',num2str(er),'%']);

%% display the optimal parameters
L = length(params)/3;
ai = params(1:L);
bi = params(L+1:2*L);
tetai = params(2*L+1:3*L);

figure;
plot(t,data*6/max(data),'b');
hold on
plot(t,peaks*2,'ro');
plot(t,phase,'c--','linewidth',1);
plot(t,pphase,'g','linewidth',1);
grid;
xlabel('time (sec.)');
legend('Scaled ECG','ECG Peaks','phase','shifted phase');

figure;
errorbar(meanphase,ECGmean,ECGsd/2);
hold on;
plot(meanphase,ECGmean,'r');
legend('SD Bar','Mean ECG');
xlabel('phase (rads.)');
grid


 % % % plot(d,'g');
% % % plot(dd,'m');
% % % plot(ddd,'k');
% % % plot(n(I),y(I),'ro','linewidth',3);
% % % plot(n(II),y(II),'go','linewidth',3);
% % % plot(n(J),y(J),'ro','linewidth',3);
% % % plot(n(JJ),y(JJ),'go','linewidth',3);
% % % plot(n(K),y(K),'ro','linewidth',1);
% % % plot(n(KK),y(KK),'go','linewidth',3);
% % % plot(n(UU),y(UU),'go','linewidth',3);
% % % grid
```

Data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OieiPKJemlAqPXkhje9s0d5b9uCy0etb

Comment: Please edit your post to include that code instead of directing us to a third site. Please make it sure that you provide it in the form of a [MCVE]

Comment: i solve this error, by Compute objective function in vectorized:
the modification in function ECGOptimizeModel(x, indexes, meanphase)

can be, in this line:
options = optimoptions('particleswarm','SwarmSize',length(InitParams),'HybridFcn',@fminsearch,'Vectorized','on');

but i ends with error:

Error using particleswarm>makeState (line 699)
When OPTIONS.Vectorized is 'on', your objective function must return a vector of length equal to
the number of particles specified in OPTIONS.SwarmSize.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, be sure your question contains enough information so that it's possible for anyone to be able to determine your answer actually is the solution (i.e. not just because you say it is).